# full screen mode (25*80) command line scripting

Tags: command-line, vbscript, fullscreen

when you run a script (such as vbscript) from 25*80 (full screen mode of dos prompt) and that your script call a windows application (such as notepad), at the end of the operation, focus remains on the desktop (although "command prompt" at the taskbar minimized and wait for only one "{enter}" to go back in 25*80 full screen command prompt)

how can i do that? (go back to full screen command prompt at the end of the call windows app. from my script)

Answer (score 0):

look at shell command START

Comment: make yuor command prompt shortcut in fullscreen mode (25*80) by setting property & dbl click on it. @ the prompt enter "start /b notepad" & then push enter & see what happen. how can you return to command prompt in full screen mode & how to automate it?

Answer (score 0):

Make your command prompt shortcut in fullscreen mode (25*80) by setting property & dbl click on it.

At the prompt enter `start /b notepad`, and then push enter and see what happen. How can you return to command prompt in full screen mode and how to automate it?